# Unable to install pycrypto on ubuntu 14.04 with python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, pycrypto

I'm trying to install stream package with `pip install stream_django` which has pycrypto dependency. So while installing pycrypto dependecy it returns me `RuntimeError: autoconf error` error.
How can i install pycrypto on ubuntu 14.04 with python3

Comment: What has django-rest-framework to do with that ?

Comment: Thought someone might need that tag... Coz I'm just working with django-rest.

Answer (score 0):

I had a other error with pycrypto, so I used pycryptodome.
It basicly is the same. You can install it by typing:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```